# Windows CE 7 development in VS 2008 Pro

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-embedded-compact

I'm new to WEC7 - but I'm trying to write an app in Visual C# for WEC7 to be deployed to a TI OMAP 3530 board.

However, I'm having trouble installing WEC7. It seems to installs just fine on my development virtual machine, but when I go to VS2008 > New project > Visual C# > Smart Device Project, I can only target the Windows Mobile 5 platform.

Why is that so? What have I done wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Connect do device and deploy your application there
Possible your need `BSP` for your board, and `WinCE 7 iso` for build target platform .bin